# React router basic implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement React router and I have a class called App from which I want to call ExpenseApp. For ExpenseApp to work, it requires 'data' which I want to pass. Also, my first page of get loaded should be ExpenseApp. As far as I understood react-router, the class name to be specified in the '/' path is the first page to be loaded. The question is how can I pass data from react router to the component.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {ExpenseApp} from './expense-app.js'
import {Switch, BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import {FullBlog} from './FullBlog.js'

var data=[
  {
    "Author":"Dan Brown",
    "Book":"Inferno"
      },
  {
    "Author":"Jeffrey Archer",
    "Book":"Be careful what you wish for"
},

  {
    "Author":"Paulo Coelho",
    "Book":"The Alchemist"
  }
];
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
                <Route path='/' component={ExpenseApp}/>
                <Route path='fullblog' component={FullBlog}/>
            </Router>
            )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'))
```

And normally when I was displaying the component without using the react-router, I was doing something like

I am still confused with the concepts of react-router, how can I implement this?

Comment: fetch the data inside `ExpenseApp` component.  Could that work?

Comment: Actually I have to pass the data so that the hierarchy could be maintained.@DavinTryon

Comment: [React Router Training](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) Give it a read!, also do what Davin said, you don't pass data to the router but components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try this one :

```
 <Router>
     <Route exact path='/' render={() => <ExpenseApp data={data} />}/>
     <Route path='fullblog' component={FullBlog}/>
 </Router>
```

this is using react router v4, hope can solve your issue :)

Comment: Just a <div></div>is required to contain the <Route> tags

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you usually would want to fetch data from within the component, but if it is not possible or you do not want to do this, you could try using `decorateComponentWithProps` (https://github.com/belle-ui/decorateComponentWithProps)

```
import decorateComponentWithProps from 'decorate-component-with-props';

// ...
<Route path='/' component={decorateComponentWithProps(ExpenseApp, {data})} />
```

Given that the `ExpenseApp`'s prop name is `data`

Edit: As found out in the comments, you also need to change

```
import {Switch, BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
```

to

```
import {Switch, BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
```

For the code to work, or you can also change the usage of `<Router />` to `<BrowserRouter />`

Comment: And in ExpenseApp a simple this.state={data:this.props.data} would work?

Comment: Technically, yes. But you already have the exact same data inside the `props` object, why would you map it to `state` directly?

Comment: Was just trying to understand the function decorateComponentWithProps()

Comment: Ah, well, yes. The method expects an object as the second argument that will then be mapped onto the props of the component (the first argument).

Comment: Actually, that's another problem of your code. Change "BrowserRouter" to "BrowserRouter as Router" (without quotes!)

Comment: I get maximum size limit exceeded error after doing that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149834/discussion-between-simon-nussbaumer-and-user7816606).